# how to avoid printing html code inside textbox as value

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a dynamic table and getting td values from array, my goal was when I click on any cell that convert to input box and get this td value as input value so we can change and when I click on another td the previous td turn back to it's original position with new or same old value, Now this is almost happening, problem is when I click on td it turn to input box and when I click again on the same input box it prints it's html code inside the text box as it's value and then the all td's go crazy, like this:  it creates two input boxes in same time and sometime prints the html code inside td without creating input box. I am new to these things trying to learn and stuck on this for two days please help me to come out. Thanks in advance

```
var getInput = ""; var inputsParent = ""; var inputs = ""; var thisInHtml = ""; var getInputVal = "";
var thisTdInnerHtml = ""; var input = ""; var flag = 1;

var getInputLength = getInput.length+1;
  for(var j=0; j<allTds.length;j++){         
   allTds[j].onclick = function(){ 
    thisInHtml = this.innerHTML;                 
     var thisId = this.id;                                             

               if(inputs.length != 0){
               inputsParent.removeChild(inputs);   
               inputsParent.innerHTML = getInputVal;     
               flag = 1;
                }

              this.innerHTML = thisInHtml;  
              if(getInputVal != ""){
              input = this.innerHTML =  "<input id='thisInputId' type='text' value='"+thisInHtml+"' style='width: 100px;'>";
              getInput = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
              getInputVal = document.getElementById("thisInputId").value;
          }

              if(getInputLength > 0){                      
               for(var k =0; k<getInputLength;k++){
                 inputsParent = getInput[k].parentNode;
                 inputs = inputsParent.childNodes[0];
        }
     } 
   }            
  }
}
```

Comment: create fidde/snippet for code

Comment: If you want a quick solution for your problem, setup a jsfiddle and include that in your question. People will be faster to help you.

Comment: how can I  invoke this question again here in stack